# c libxml listing specific content

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I have an xml file with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vm_list>
<vm name="Win2k_SQL2000 (1)" type="VM">53370afc-7b57-360c-a7a1-236f40535064</vm>
<vm name="WinXP_PRO_SP3_en_x86 (1)" type="VM">89b6d54c-4015-119b-db11-bfecf42688e6</vm>    
</vm_list>
```

Here is a part of my code to get content of nodes "vm"

```
cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc); 
while(cur ! = NULL){
puts("loop");
if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
      if (!(xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "vm")))
        {
          key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
          puts((char *) key);
          xmlFree(key);
        }
    }
 cur = cur->next;
 }
```

But it gives me the following result:

```
loop
loop
53370afc-7b57-360c-a7a1-236f40535064
loop
loop
89b6d54c-4015-119b-db11-bfecf42688e6
loop
```

Of course I can retrieve it by xPath but I want to know whats wrong with this code..

Comment: Sorry, you forgot to say what you expected. Looks like normal working code to me.

Comment: I need to get the string node content, UUID, 53370afc-7b57-360c-a7a1-236f40535064 for example.

Comment: Don't you get the string node content (third line in your example output)? There are also "wrong" nodes (TEXT nodes for newlines, which you skip), is it a problem?